# How do I create a maven multi-module project with trunk/branches/tags structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, repository

I'm required to check-in my project, and in Eclipse I created the parent and child maven with maven. 
So my structure so far looks like:

parent maven project

--src
   --module1
   --module2

however, I need the folder structure to look like:

parent maven project
   --tags
   --branches
   --trunk
   ----module1
   ----module2

If I try to create the folders manually and move the modules into a trunk folder, when importing into Eclipse the child POM.xmls' are not recognized by Eclipse and only the parent pom.xml is read.

How do I go about creating this project structure so I can check-in?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The os I'm using is windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The os I'm using is windows 7

I suggest to use a tool such as TortoiseSVN to create your trunk/branches/tags structures.

Afterwards copy your project to your working copy.